# Spring Boot RestController DELETE request fails without .csrf().disable()

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have a Spring Boot Rest Service proof of concept.

I have this for my security:  (obviously a poor real implmentation).

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MySecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        /* not production grade quality */
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

//    @Override
//    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
//        web.debug(true);
//    }

}
```

***Using Postman***:
All of my GETs were working fine.  Then I added a **DELETE** request.  and got

```
{
    "timestamp": "blah blah blah",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/v1/mything/1"
}
```

Postman setup: (not rocket science)

```
DELETE
http://localhost:8080/v1/mythings/1
```

So I added the ".csrf().disable()", and my DELETE works.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MySecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        /* not production grade quality */
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable(); /* had to add this "Cross Site Request Forgery" disable for DELETE operations */
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

//    @Override
//    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
//        web.debug(true);
//    }

}
```

But my question is WHY does **.csrf().disable()** .. allow DELETE requests?  Seems *somewhat* unrelated.

Thanks.

My full rest controller below:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class MyThingController {

    private final Logger logger;
    private final IMyThingManager mythingManager;

    /* The Inject annotation is the signal for which constructor to use for IoC when there are multiple constructors.  Not needed in single constructor scenarios */
    @Inject
    public MyThingController(IMyThingManager mythingManager) {
        this(LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyThingController.class), mythingManager);
    }

    public MyThingController(Logger lgr, IMyThingManager mythingManager) {
        if (null == lgr) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Logger is null");
        }

        if (null == mythingManager) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("IMyThingManager is null");
        }

        this.logger = lgr;
        this.mythingManager = mythingManager;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/mythings", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    Collection<MyThingDto> getAllMyThings() {
        Collection<MyThingDto> returnItems = this.mythingManager.getAll();
        return returnItems;
    }


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "mythings/{mythingKey}")
    ResponseEntity<MyThingDto> getMyThingById(@PathVariable Long mythingKey) {

        this.logger.info(String.format("Method getMyThingById called. (mythingKey=\"%1s\")", mythingKey));

        Optional<MyThingDto> foundItem = this.mythingManager.getSingle(mythingKey);
        ResponseEntity<MyThingDto> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

        if (foundItem.isPresent()) {
            responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(foundItem.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return responseEntity;
    }




    @RequestMapping(value = "mythings/{mythingKey}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Integer> deleteUser(@PathVariable("mythingKey") Long mythingKey) {
        this.logger.info(String.format("Method deleteUser called. (mythingKey=\"%1s\")", mythingKey));

        int rowCount = this.mythingManager.deleteByKey(mythingKey);
        int rowCount = 1; /* use this to "fake it" */
        ResponseEntity<Integer> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

        if (rowCount > 0) {
            responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(rowCount, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return responseEntity;
    }


}
```

Comment: CSRF protection checks for a CSRF token on changing methods like POST, PUT, DELETE. And as a REST API is stateless you don't have a token in a cookie. That's why you have to disable it for REST APIs

Comment: Does this answer your question? If yes I would add my comment as the answer with some links

Comment: Done.  Don't forget about my well phrased and clear cut question as well.  :)

Comment: Sure ;-).......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSRF protection checks for a CSRF token on changing methods like POST, PUT, DELETE. And as a REST API is stateless you don't have a token in a cookie. That's why you have to disable it for REST APIs.

**References**

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166724/should-i-use-csrf-protection-on-rest-api-endpoints
- Spring Security Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#csrf
- Guide to CSRF Protection in Spring https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf

Answer (score 0):

The guide to CSRF Protection says: "However, if our stateless API uses a session cookie authentication, we need to enable CSRF protection as we'll see next."

For this case the solution is not to disable csrf. Is there another possibility to use CSRF Protection with DELETE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).